# egrep for access log records that don't match some string

Tags: regex, grep

I have an egrep that does a good job at extracting all GET /admin/hb records from a Jetty Access Log

```
egrep '^.*? ".+? /admin/hb .*?".*?$' /m1/logs/ap*access*2013_03_19.log
```

I would now like to get all the lines that aren't "GET /admin/hb".  Its simple enough with egrep -v...

```
egrep -v '^.*? ".+? /admin/hb .*?".*?$' /m1/logs/ap*access*2013_03_19.log
```

...but I will ultimately be putting this expresion into a Groovy script and would like to know how to negate the "/admin/hb" part.  My weak attempt at negative lookaround failed; it matches no lines at all.

```
egrep '^.*? ".+? ^(?!/admin/hb) .*?".*?$' /m1/logs/ap*access*2013_03_19.log
```

How can I get egrep to produce all the access log lines that don't match /admin/hb?

The test data set follows.  I expect the solution to skip the first line, but match the next two:

```
127.0.0.1 -  -  [20/Mar/2013:16:37:08 +0000] "GET /admin/hb HTTP/1.1" 200 105  4
10.23.68.60 -  -  [20/Mar/2013:16:37:08 +0000] "GET /$PIT$/AUS/admin/hb HTTP/1.1" 200 0  4
10.23.68.64 -  -  [20/Mar/2013:16:36:47 +0000] "GET /handsets/dmhc HTTP/1.1" 200 0  1
```

Comment: Hmmm.  This answer is related but I can't figure out how to integrate it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work with your version of grep?

```
grep -P '^.*? "\S+?(?! /admin/hb) .*?".*?$' groovy
10.23.68.60 -  -  [20/Mar/2013:16:37:08 +0000] "GET /$PIT$/AUS/admin/hb HTTP/1.1" 200 0  4
10.23.68.64 -  -  [20/Mar/2013:16:36:47 +0000] "GET /handsets/dmhc HTTP/1.1" 200 0  1
```

Comment: That does work, thanks.  But I'm left scratching my head why the same expression doesn't work through my egrep.  Hmmm.

Comment: Because ?! is a perlism, and using -P invokes the perlre personality of grep.